# Why convert to grayscale opencv?

Tags: opencv

I'm doing some basic face detection in opencv, and every example code I look at they convert to grayscale and then perform face detect on the grayscale...

At first i thought it was for performance reasons, but I did a comparision and found no significant performance boost.

This code:

```
faceCascade.detectMultiScale(*image, *faces, 1.1, 3, CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(60,60));
```

Performs about the same as this code:

```
Mat gray;
cvtColor(*image, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, *faces, 1.1, 3, CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(60,60));
```

So this begs the question, why does everyone convert to gray scale in opencv?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everyone converts to grayscale because many functions expect grayscale. From [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html) `faceCascade.detectMultiScale()` also expects grayscale:

`CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale(const Mat& image,...)`

*image – Matrix of the type CV_8U containing an image where objects are detected.*

And `CV_8U` is a 1-channel image, as opposed to `CV_8U3`, which would be a 3-channel image.

**EDIT:** If you don't convert it to grayscale before passing to the method, OpenCV will do it for you under the hood.

Comment: Then why does detectMultiScale still work even when I give it BGR?

Comment: You're giving it a pointer. Have you tried feeding it with the image instead of the pointer?

The documentation you sent me also says CV_8U and not CV_8U3

Comment: Actually I did more digging. Here you can find the answer to your follow up questions: http://answers.opencv.org/question/67416/is-grayscale-image-still-required-in-cascadeclassifierdetectmultiscale/

Answer (score 1):

In nutshell:

It is needed, but if you dont do it, then OpenCv will do it for you.

if you are passing the Mat-- you are passing the CV_8U (channel) information-- they can just do it for you.. this is smart.

Why have developers write three lines of code, when you can easily have them write one?

None the less, thank you for the answer and the digging.

some notes for other developers:

cvtColor takes about 3ms on a RPI3 to convert a 640x480 BGR to grayscale.

If you are doing multiple openCv methods that require grayscale, then you can have better performance if you convert to gray scale once-- and pass the grayscale into those openCv methods.